# syntax error near unexpected token `newline' for my simple if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char input;
  printf("Enter a character: ");
  scanf("%c", &input);

  if (input == 'a') {
    printf("A\n");

  } else {
    printf("B\n");
  }
  return (0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? this should be easy. I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, no syntax error here!

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: `gcc yourcode.c -o prog` for compile. then `./prog`

Comment: How do you compile your code? Please show the command line. Enclose it in '``' backticks.

Comment: Sometimes there can be a mistaken hidden character from a fault in the text editor. Try opening a new file and copying the program code back from your question (dump the old file).

Comment: This compiles and runs perfectly on ideone ([demo](http://ideone.com/oEg1UF)).

Comment: Your error is generated by `bash`, not by the C compiler. Show us how exactly you compiled your code.

Comment: No errors in your code. use this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php and check it.

Comment: oh yea hm it is working on a different compiler..something must be up with my terminal or file ill check them. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your program is perfectly correct.

The error message `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'` is produced by `bash`, the command line interpreter, not the compiler.

There are a few potential reasons for this, but here is the most likely:

- You are running the program with bash instead of having the system execute the binary, which is what happens if you typed `. ./prog` or `. prog` instead of `./prog`.

Comment: or perhaps he typed `. prog` (+1)